# Disable typescript-eslint plugin rule (no-explicit-any) with inline comment

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I have an eslint error that comes from the @typescript-eslint plugin.

> Unexpected any. Specify a different
> type.eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)

This is the no-implicit-any rule. In just one file I want to disable that rule with a comment at the top of the file.

The compiler complains if I just try a standard eslint disable:

```
/* eslint-disable  no-explicit-any */
```

> Definition for rule 'no-explicit-any' was not
> found.eslint(no-explicit-any)

I've tried to find [documentation](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) on inline rules for the TS plugin, but without much luck. I've also tried various combinations like these:

```
/* typescript-eslint-disable no-implicit-any */
/* typescript-eslint: disable no-implicit-any */
/* typescript-eslint: disable noImplicitAny */
/* typescript-eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-implicit-any */
```

There are no eslint complaints but the error will not disappear.

How do I disable an typescript-eslint rule?

Comment: It would probably be good to update this question to read `no-explicit-any` every time, since you sometimes say `no-IMPLICIT-any`, even though that's a `tsconfig` option, not an ESLint rule.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

The correct syntax is like this:

```
/* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
```

So that you directly reference the plugin via eslint.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it directly addresses OP's question about using at the top of the file, but other viewers here might want to note that unless you *really* want to disable linting for the entire file, you probably want to go with the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66659083/758334).

Answer (score 204):

add this to the .eslintrc (tslintrc) file :

```
rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"
},
```

If you see this under VSCode as well restart ESLint server via command pallette: `CTRL-Shit-P` -> type `eslint restart`, click the respective dropdown item.

Comment: The OP write "In just one file I want to disable that rule with a comment at the top of the file."

Comment: It is not OP request

Comment: It might be necessary to restart the IDE

Comment: This has no effect in my project. Did something change?

Comment: Also, this will allow using "any" all around which is kind of disabling Typescript!

Answer (score 109):

If you're attempting to disable a rule on the next line only (rather than for an entire file), adding this comment directly above the line to ignore will work:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
```

Comment: You can also disable on the same line with e.g. `  //  eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any  --  optional reason goes here`

Answer (score -2):

You may also come across the following syntax, so you would update with value of 0 if it is set to 1:

```
'@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 0,
```